# How to manage stack overflow open ID if you have two Google accounts

Tags: support, openid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Associate Multiple Google OpenIDs In One Account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74904/associate-multiple-google-openids-in-one-account)

My main open id provider is my personal Google account, and this is the open ID that my stack overflow account is linked to. great.

The problem is, that I spend most of my time logged in to my Google Apps account. So when I go to stack overflow and log in, it asks me to click my open id provider, and I click google. Google provides an open id, but not the one that is linked with my stack overflow account. This has the effect of logging me into a random stack overflow account which is not my main one, with a user id of userXYZ or something similar.

To get into my main stack overflow account, I have to sign out of my google apps account, sign into my personal google account, and then sign in to stack overflow using that open id (or manage two browsers for different websites).

That's annoying.

Can I link two open ids to the same stack overflow account? Or can I just have a user name and password (I don't really see what the problem was with user id and password anyway? It wasn't *that* bad was it?)

Comment: Voting to reopen because the duplicate target is deleted.

Comment: See also: [Two logins from same openid](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139981/two-logins-from-same-openid)

Answer (score 0):

You can add an alternate OpenID to your primary account.  Just click the "add openid" link on your profile page.

[image: Screen Shot]

Once you do that, you can log in with either one of them.