# I have multiple duplicate accounts

Tags: support, openid

Hi, I posted a question yesterday that was marked as a duplicate, but I believe that my case is slightly different. Apologies if this is wrong and I've created another duplicate.

My case differs to the question that was marked as being the same in that I have tried to associate my other google open id account with my main one, but - **I've obviously created a duplicate SO account accidentally at some point due to the multiple open id's. This is causing a problem with the addition of the second open id to my SO account.**

Because I have an account associated with the second open id, using the 'Add another open id' functionality does not work correctly

Steps to reproduce:

-Sign into Google with my personal account (primary open id provider).

-Visit stack overflow, sign in with open id, click Google as open id provider.

-I am now logged in to my main account.

-To associate second open id I now go to the user page for BombDefused.

-Click 'add another open id' link.

-Sign out of my personal Google account.

-Sign in with my Google apps account.

-Back on the SO open id sign in page, click the Google button.

-Now, instead of having two open ids associated with my main account, I find I am just logged into my duplicate account.

What makes me confident that SO is getting confused, **is that in the attached screen print, you can see the user id for the duplicate account, but all of the user information on the page for my primary account.** If I continue around the site, the credentials from the duplicate account are used.

I presume if the second SO account is deleted, this problem will go away.

**Can you please delete the duplicate SO account - user478454 - you will see that there is not much data associated with that account.**

Thank you for your help.

[image]

My original question:

[How to manage stack overflow open ID if you have two Google accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75084/how-to-manage-stack-overflow-open-id-if-you-have-two-google-accounts)

Which was marked as similar to:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74904/associate-multiple-google-openids-in-one-account

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you have to email us with the urls to each account and we can merge them.

Comment: So I mail you with the URL of mine and yours account and you merge my account with yours? Isn't this a giant security hole?

Comment: @Time Strict account verifications are done before accounts are merged. Since only devs can do this, the room for error  is very narrow.

Comment: @Diago nice, very nice.

Comment: Thanks you for this,  this happened to me today.  Its a bit odd.