# Two logins from same openid

Tags: support, user-accounts, merge-accounts

I was wondering if it was possible to change the Google account I have associated with my StackOverflow account.

The old email I have registered at google (and associated with my SO account) is no longer in service and I'd like to change it over to my newer Gmail account to sync all my services.

I saw the "my logins" option in the account section, but since the account I currently am logged in with (the old one) is also provided via Google OpenID, it just assumes I am already logged in and proceeds to the SO homepage.

Would it be possible to change the Google account associated with my SO, or add another google account as a valid login even though this would be two accounts from one OpenID provider?

Thanks.

Comment: If you log out of Google before you try to add the new OpenID then I think it should work. It works for me, anyway - I have two Gmail accounts associated with my SE account, and logging out of Google will prompt me for another login if I try to add a new ID via Google.

Comment: Ace!  Want to pop that in an answer and I'll accept?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I've done in the past (I have two Google accounts on my SE account):

- Log out of Google, or whatever OpenID provider you're trying to add a duplicate of
- Go to your SO account page and click the "my logins" link
- Select your OpenID provider

As long as you're not logged into the provider when you select it, you should get prompted for a login/password as normal (this works with Google, at least). Once you've done that, you could also remove the old account my clicking the "my logins" link and then clicking the `x` button to the right of the old OpenID account on the dialog that pops up.